# Count visitors on your site with django

Tags: python, django

I want to import countviews app and embed it into my project.

I'm using `django 1.10`, `python 2.7`

I used `pip install django-hitcount` and add `hitcount` into installed apps (myapp/settings.py).

When I run the server, I get an error:

```
myapphitcount module not found.
```

In directory MYAPP, I don't have folder hitcount.

Should I run `python manage.py startapp hitcount`?

Comment: Care to post the relevant part of your settings.py ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you forgot to add a comma:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'myapp' # this must be followed by a comma
    'hitcount'
)
```

Since you haven't added a comma, python concatenates two strings 'myapp' and 'hitcount' into 'myapphitcount', so django can't find such application.